# Moment of inertia of hemisphere

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

I want to find the moment of inertia of the hemisphere shown in the picture about the $O$ axis.

[image]

I am getting different results depending on the approach.

1. The moment of inertia of the hemisphere about an axis parallel to $O$ passing through its Center of Mass (CoM) [is](https://www.efunda.com/math/solids/solids_display.cfm?SolidName=Hemisphere)

$
I_{CoM} = \frac{83}{320}ma^2
$

wherein $m$ is the mass of the hemisphere.

The distance from the $O$ axis to its CoM is $\frac{5}{8}a$.
Therefore, from the parallel axis theorem,

$
I_O = \frac{83}{320}ma^2 + m(\frac{5}{8}a)^2=\frac{13}{20}ma^2
$

2. The moment of inertia of the hemisphere about an axis parallel to $O$ passing through $a$ (the "base" of the hemisphere) [is](https://www.efunda.com/math/solids/solids_display.cfm?SolidName=Hemisphere)

$
I_{CoM} = \frac{2}{5}ma^2
$

Therefore, from the parallel axis theorem,

$
I_O = \frac{2}{5}ma^2 + ma^2=\frac{7}{5}ma^2
$

3. The general expression for the moment of inertia is:

$
I_O = \int_m{r^2dm} = \int_m{(x^2+y^2)\cdot\rho dV} = \int_m{(x^2+y^2)\cdot\rho \cdot (\pi \cdot y^2 \cdot dx)}
$

Substituting $y^2=a^2-(x-a)^2$, we get

$
I_O = \int_0^a{(x^2+(a^2-(x-a)^2))\cdot\rho \cdot (\pi \cdot (a^2-(x-a)^2) \cdot dx)} = \frac{5}{6} \pi \rho a^5
$

The mass of the hemisphere is $m=\frac{2}{3}\pi \rho a^3$, so the expression above can be written in terms of the mass $m$ as

$
I_O = \frac{5}{6} \frac{3}{2} \left( \frac{2}{3} \pi \rho a^3 \right) a^2 = \frac{15}{12}ma^2 = \frac{5}{4}ma^2
$

4. Since the differential volume in (3) was $dV=\pi y^2 dx$, maybe the general expression for the moment of inertia reduces to:

$
I_O = \int_m{r^2dm} = \int_m{x^2 \cdot\rho dV} = \int_m{x^2 \cdot\rho \cdot (\pi \cdot y^2 \cdot dx)}
$

Which, after substituting $y^2=a^2-(x-a)^2$, results in:

$
I_O = \int_0^a{x^2 \cdot\rho \cdot (\pi \cdot (a^2-(x-a)^2) \cdot dx)} = \frac{3}{10} \pi \rho a^5 = \frac{9}{20}ma^2
$

In summary, four different approaches and four different results. What am I missing here?

Comment: how can an  " axis parallel to O"  be ?? are looking for axes parallel to $y$ axis ($x = c$) or parallel to $x$ axis ($y=c$) ?

Comment: axis parallel to $O$ is the axis parallel to the $z$ axis

Comment: The mass of the half sphere is $m$

Comment: @Thales: sorry, my bad.

Comment: @Thales: then please amend your post accordingly !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. is correct, $\dfrac{83}{320}+\dfrac{5^2}{8^2}=\dfrac{13}{20}.$
2. is incorrect, the parallel axis theorem works with an axis through the gravity center;
3. is incorrect, there is no account for the $z$ coordinate.